# Draw svg with dynamic value on canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, canvas

I want to be able to draw svg with dynamic value (color) to the canvas.
I'd tried making the svg react component, so I could pass the color to the svg, but I'm then confused how to draw the react svg component to the canvas.

P.S. Best would be if the svg would be stored in seperate file.

Working static svg example:

```
import ant_skin_url from '../../assets/AntSkin.svg';

const ant_skin = new Image();
ant_skin.src = ant_skin_url;

context.drawImage(
  ant_skin,
  i * width_cell,
  ii * height_cell,
  width_cell,
  height_cell,
);
```

React svg component, but confused how to handle the output (draw this in the canvas):

```
export const AntSkin = (color) => 
  <svg>
    ...
  </svg>
```

Comment: Is it have to rendered inside a canvas? If so, I don't think there is a point of importing from the svg file. Instead, combine the svg content with the variable (e.g. `'<svg><path d="..." fill="' + color + '" /></svg>` ) and render it inside a canvas

Comment: I just wanted to make it seperated, but it doesn't have to be that way. With the method you're suggesting, how would I render this svg into the canvas?  @MoshFeu

Comment: To be more specific, how can I draw to the canvas from this object, which I got by console logging the variable with svg element. https://i.imgur.com/vx9MlPh.png

Comment: This is what I mean - https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-wiles-lj6wbg?file=/src/Icon.js

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much, you can send your snippet as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't want to render the svg but take it into a canvas, importing from *.svg* won't be much helpful.

You can create a component that:

1. Receives a color as prop
2. Has the svg content as string

On mount, it combines the svg string and the color, converts it to base64 (this is what webpack does when importing from *.svg*) and feed the canvas the same way you do.

This is how it looks

```js
import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from "react";

export const Icon = ({ color }) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const svg = useMemo(
    () => `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" height="100px" width="100px">
    <g>
      <path color="${color}" d="M28.1,36.6c4.6,1.9,12.2,1.6,20.9,1.1c8.9-0.4,19-0.9,28.9,0.9c6.3,1.2,11.9,3.1,16.8,6c-1.5-12.2-7.9-23.7-18.6-31.3   c-4.9-0.2-9.9,0.3-14.8,1.4C47.8,17.9,36.2,25.6,28.1,36.6z"/>
      <path color="${color}" d="M70.3,9.8C57.5,3.4,42.8,3.6,30.5,9.5c-3,6-8.4,19.6-5.3,24.9c8.6-11.7,20.9-19.8,35.2-23.1C63.7,10.5,67,10,70.3,9.8z"/>
      <path color="${color}" d="M16.5,51.3c0.6-1.7,1.2-3.4,2-5.1c-3.8-3.4-7.5-7-11-10.8c-2.1,6.1-2.8,12.5-2.3,18.7C9.6,51.1,13.4,50.2,16.5,51.3z"/>
      <path color="${color}" d="M9,31.6c3.5,3.9,7.2,7.6,11.1,11.1c0.8-1.6,1.7-3.1,2.6-4.6c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4-0.6c-2.9-3.3-3.1-9.2-0.6-17.6   c0.8-2.7,1.8-5.3,2.7-7.4c-5.2,3.4-9.8,8-13.3,13.7C10.8,27.9,9.8,29.7,9,31.6z"/>
      <path color="${color}" d="M15.4,54.7c-2.6-1-6.1,0.7-9.7,3.4c1.2,6.6,3.9,13,8,18.5C13,69.3,13.5,61.8,15.4,54.7z"/>
      <path color="${color}" d="M39.8,57.6C54.3,66.7,70,73,86.5,76.4c0.6-0.8,1.1-1.6,1.7-2.5c4.8-7.7,7-16.3,6.8-24.8c-13.8-9.3-31.3-8.4-45.8-7.7   c-9.5,0.5-17.8,0.9-23.2-1.7c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4c-1,1.7-2,3.4-2.9,5.1C28.2,49.7,33.8,53.9,39.8,57.6z"/>
      <path color="${color}" d="M26.2,88.2c3.3,2,6.7,3.6,10.2,4.7c-3.5-6.2-6.3-12.6-8.8-18.5c-3.1-7.2-5.8-13.5-9-17.2c-1.9,8-2,16.4-0.3,24.7   C20.6,84.2,23.2,86.3,26.2,88.2z"/>
      <path color="${color}" d="M30.9,73c2.9,6.8,6.1,14.4,10.5,21.2c15.6,3,32-2.3,42.6-14.6C67.7,76,52.2,69.6,37.9,60.7C32,57,26.5,53,21.3,48.6   c-0.6,1.5-1.2,3-1.7,4.6C24.1,57.1,27.3,64.5,30.9,73z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>`,
    [color]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const image = new Image();
    const context = ref.current.getContext("2d");

    image.src = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${window.btoa(svg)}`;
    image.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    };
  }, [svg]);

  return <canvas ref={ref} width="200" height="200" />;
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-wiles-lj6wbg?file=/src/Icon.js)